# avconv/ffmpeg command to encode nice full hd webm for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, html5-video, electron, avconv

People from the artistic direction gave me big `.mov` and `.mp4` that I need to put on a web app, but so far they are so huge that decoding/rendering is kinda bad on chrome (this is a chrome only experience since it will run on electron at the end).

I'd like to re-encode them in `.webm` since it seems to have the best support in chrome.

But I'm kinda lost on how to re-encode them without significative visual quality lost.

For now I use (taken from https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8)

```
ffmpeg -i myVid.mp4 -c:v libvpx -crf 8 -b:v 2M -c:a libvorbis myVid.webm
```

So, does anyone have a nice `avconv`/`ffmpeg` command that will produce nice and easy to render `.webm` ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
ffmpeg -i myVid.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 8 -b:v 0 -c:a libvorbis myVid.webm
```

VP9 is better than VP8 (libpvx), so it will produce better quality at the same bitrate. When using true CRF mode, `-b:v` has to be specified but it should be 0, otherwise you'll be using constrained quality mode. Increase CRF value till the quality and size is acceptable.

Comment: Hello thanks for your comment. How VP9 decoding is handled by low end machines (intel NUC i3) ?

Comment: Don't know. You can compare processor utilization for playback of VP8 and VP9 encodes on your own machine and get an idea.